# Long running function execution in c#.net app

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a desktop app developed in C#/.Net which has a lot of long-running processes. The UI is stuck while those run. Which definitely irritates the user.

For this reason I am using a background process, which helps.

But I have to use that on every form; the app has more than a hundred forms which need to use a background process.

Now, I am trying to make a function to which I pass a function to run that function in a non-UI thread or in a background process.

Is that possible?

Can I send different custom functions to one central function that executes those in a background process?

Comment: Look into the await async pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: In addtion to `ThreadPool`, you can also create multiple threads via [TaskFactory Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory?view=netcore-3.1).

Answer (score 1):

.NET has it built in, see

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=netcore-3.1

you can queue things like

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s) => { /* stuff to do in the background */ }, thing);
```

This allows you to queue functions to be executed by a threadpool thread.  The `thing` variable will be passed in as an object via the `s` parameter when the thread starts work on your function.

If you want to update things on your UI thread from a background thread you should check if `InvokeIsRequired` and if so, `Invoke` the change  ( basically it passes a function back to your UI thread to update UI elements )

This may not be the best approach in your situation though, but I'm not really sure what your background work is.

Comment: Background process includes only data saving to database, and at time of form initializing we have to update controls properties.